# Java compiler null when creating jar with all dependencies

Tags: java, maven, groovy, gradle

I am trying to create a jar with all of the dependencies in it that will host a small Groovy program that uses the Java compiler API to generate a class at runtime. I'm using Gradle One Jar to produce this, however I've also tried the Maven assembly plugin and achieved the same result. Here's the code that's failing:

```
def compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()
assert compiler != null
```

Result when running `java -jar` on my jar file:

```
Exception in thread "main" Assertion failed:

assert compiler != null
       |        |
       null     false
```

I'm guessing that this might be a manifest issue with it excluding the appropriate JDK jars that contain the compiler. Any suggestions on how to fix that? I don't need a Gradle or Maven-specific suggestion, thought that would help.

Comment: Have you tried executing your app with a `JDK`'s `java` command?

Answer (score 0):

I think what Peter tried hinting is that you most probably run your java command using a JRE, which does not include the tools.jar for the compiler. You require the tools.jar or. better, an installed JDK.

If you want to know how to add classes or jars to the classpath part of the manifest file you can read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html